# How to catch column name on SQLiteConstraintException Unique Constraint failed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception, insert

I'm testing my app and tried to insert a duplicate record in SQLite. And Java returned an exception with exactly the duplicate column. Can I pick up the error information to display to the user a message with the information he typed duplicate?

My code:

```
        ContentValues valores;
    valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("nome", nome);
    valores.put("apelido", apelido);

    try {
        resultado = db.insert("escolas", null, valores);
    }catch (SQLiteConstraintException e){
        Log.e("dop",e.getLocalizedMessage()+"");
        Log.e("dop",e.getMessage()+"");
        Log.e("dop",e.getCause()+"");
        Log.e("dop",e.getStackTrace()+"");
        Log.e("dop",e.getSuppressed()+"");
    }
```

Exception in logcat

```
10-12 18:59:49.747 24576-24576/br.com.brhuearts.escola1 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting nome=A apelido=B
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: escolas.nome (code 2067)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
    at br.com.brhuearts.escola1.presenter.PresenterEscola.insertEscola(PresenterEscola.java:51)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception would be caught (*not caught by the insert method, which is why you code doesn't catch it*) if you use the alternative convenience method **[insertOrThrow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))**.

as per :-

```
    resultado = db.insertOrThrow("escolas", null, valores);
```

Alternately, you could just check that the **long** returned by the **insert** is 1 or greater (should be -1 to indicate row not inserted, should never be 0). However, a duplicate may not necessarily be the only cause of a row not being inserted.

Comment: Or you could check to ensure the insert will work first.